# Is there a way to return void in int type method

Tags: java, class, methods

I was trying to create a method to check if a number is a prime or not but while creating the method I am getting 0 instead of `void`. Is there a way to skip where I am getting 0 with `void`. If not,suggest any other way please.

I tried int replacing `a` with `null` but casting from `null` to `int` is not possible

```
public int getPrime(int n) {

    int a =0;
    boolean k = true;
    for (int i = 2 ; i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0) k = false;


    }
    if(k==true) { a = n;

    return a;}
    else {return null;} //Here is the problem
```

Comment: Use a wrapper class: `public Integer getPrime(...`, you can then return `null`. Or you can do it with `Optional<Integer>` which is better.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "I am getting 0 instead of void" - `void` is just a return type, not a value. As you've noted, you can't use `null` for an `int` either - although you could change method to return `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Not possible. Would suggest you return an integer that can't be achieved otherwise. return -1 often does the trick (or use the ways Aniket suggested)

Comment: @JonSkeet for example 4 is not prime so it should not return 0 in output instead it should not show anything

Comment: This is what I want

Comment: Looks like you return `n` when the number is a prime, and otherwise try to return a something that should say "not prime". Why not return a `boolean`?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yes but instead of returning not prime it should not return anything

Comment: *Is it prime?* is a yes/no question, you could return a `boolean`, `true` if number is prime and `false` if it is not. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957570/prime-numbers-test-in-java (scroll to the very end for actual useful code)

Comment: The purpose of this when I run this method in loop in any other class to get primes upto certain number it should give me only primes only and skip the non primes(right now it prints 0 for non primes )

Comment: *instead of returning not prime it should not return anything* - Why? What would you do with that result (`void`, `null`, let's pretend it's possible) afterwards?

Comment: @Aman You can do that from the code you are calling this function from. If `getPrime()` returns `false`, skip it.

Comment: @Ivar exactly sir that is what I wanted

Comment: @Aman What is stopping you? Change the `int` to `boolean` as others have suggested and go for it. We can't help you with that since you haven't shown us the code that is calling the `isPrime()` function.

Comment: @Ivar thnx a lot I have figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Use non-primitive types here. Integer vs int. That will allow you to return null where needed.

Comment: Correct, but please explain better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check if your number is primary or not, the method must return boolean not int.

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2 ; i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is not the most optimal algorithm, but it works with true types.

Answer (score 0):

Yes-no prime check with `boolean` result:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
  if(n<2)
    return false;
  for(int i=(int)Math.sqrt(n); i>=2; i--)
    if(n%i == 0)return false;
  return true;
}
```

Print primes, do not print non-primes:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    if(isPrime(i))
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/nNiY1T